# hide elements after filter using jquery

Tags: jquery

Why this code don't hide selected elements:

```
$(selector).filter(function() {
     return true;
}).hide();
```

Although this code hides:

```
$(selector).hide();
```

How to hide elements using filter in `jquery`?

In this example I used simple filter, that always true - only for example.

Comment: Can you reproduce here `->` [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5es6/1/

Comment: @efr take a look at my answer

Comment: @efr if you use .filter method is there any error in browser's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(selector).filter(function() {
     return this; //here pass this to return filter object
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of returning true `return this` so change this:

```
return true;
```

to this:

```
return this;
```

Comment: That is actually working as Arun posted a fiddle link but i think OP should return the object itself out of the filter method.

Comment: Or i would add that there might be some js error in browser's console and OP has not posted or looked at that..^^ _...my assumption..._.

Comment: Yes, If there might be an error, even your code will not work. I am sorry but i am curious about `return this` as i can't find it on http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex may be you need to look at this just a little desc. it says _....A function used as a test for each element in the set. **this** is the current DOM element....._

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but that doesn't says, you need to return `this`, actually i was reading the paragraph just underneath  that says - _The second form of this method allows us to filter elements against a function rather than a selector. For each element, if the function returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded. Suppose we have a somewhat more involved HTML snippet_